# duplicating a CCSprite

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, ccsprite

I have a `CCSprite` object and I want to make a copy of it in another `CCSprite`. Then I want to show that copy. I have tasted this code but it makes a run-time error.

```
CCSprite* copy=CCSprite::spriteWithTexture(original->getTexture());
```

How can I make a copy of my `CCSprite`?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have a many duplicate sprite, you'll need to store your sprites on CCArray, then call again the function for adding sprites using schedule for the function

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the original's texture not be deleted when the copy is using it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into CCObject::copy()?

I frequently use this technique for copying actions. CCSprite derives from CCObject, so although i have not tried, you might be able to copy a sprite by calling copy() on your sprite instances.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this for speed?

If so, you should be using "sprite sheets". With the sprite sheet, a set of sprite frames (graphics) are loaded into the texture memory, then each time your create a sprite with any of those sprite frames the system is actually using the same texture that is already in memory. Also, when drawing the sprites on the screen, any sprite that is using that texture does so in a "batch" (all at the same time) saving processing cycles (it's fast).

For an example see this project. The car and cat sprites are loaded in a sprite sheet:
http://www.gmtdev.com/blog/2011/08/19/how-to-use-box2d-for-just-collision-detection-with-cocos2d-x/

Answer (score 0):

cocos2dx did not provide clone method for sprite.You had to make it yourself by taking texture of first sprite and create a sprite with that texture in this way.

Sprite *clonedSprite = Sprite::createWithTexture(originalSprite->getTexture());